# Cordova splash screen directory name error

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm trying to generate splash screens for my Cordova project, I've made my splash screens with the filenames: `screen-hdpi-landscape` etc, and in my config file I have:

```
<platform name="android">
        <splash density="hdpi-landscape" src="res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-landscape.png" />
        <splash density="ldpi-landscape" src="res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-landscape.png" />
        <splash density="mdpi-landscape" src="res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-landscape.png" />
        <splash density="xhdpi-landscape" src="res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-landscape.png" />
        <splash density="hdpi-portrait" src="res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png" />
        <splash density="ldpi-portrait" src="res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" />
        <splash density="mdpi-portrait" src="res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png" />
        <splash density="xhdpi-portrait" src="res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" />
        <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" />
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <custom-config-file parent="/*" target="AndroidManifest.xml">
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS" />
        </custom-config-file>
        <preference name="android-windowSoftInputMode" value="adjustPan" />
    </platform>
```

However, this just gives me an error:

`> /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project-beacon/cordova/platforms/android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi-portrait: Error: Invalid resource directory name`

Anyone recommend a fix for this?

Comment: What does your project file structure look like?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have invalid directory address : drawable-xhdpi-portrait.
Double check your file names and path. I am using the following name and path and it works correctly.

```
        <splash density="land-hdpi" src="res/screen/android/splash-land-hdpi.png" />
        <splash density="land-ldpi" src="res/screen/android/splash-land-ldpi.png" />
        <splash density="land-mdpi" src="res/screen/android/splash-land-mdpi.png" />
        <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="res/screen/android/splash-land-xhdpi.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="res/screen/android/splash-land-xxhdpi.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="res/screen/android/splash-land-xxxhdpi.png" />
        <splash density="port-hdpi" src="res/screen/android/splash-port-hdpi.png" />
        <splash density="port-ldpi" src="res/screen/android/splash-port-ldpi.png" />
        <splash density="port-mdpi" src="res/screen/android/splash-port-mdpi.png" />
        <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="res/screen/android/splash-port-xhdpi.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="res/screen/android/splash-port-xxhdpi.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="res/screen/android/splash-port-xxxhdpi.png" />
```